# EC2 cannot connect to RDS on VPC. Subnet issues?

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, elastic-beanstalk

I was able to deploy our .NET app using the AWS toolkit for Visual Studio. I set up the RDS database manually (MySQL) and deployed the app using elastic beanstalk (set up on VPC). The issue was that when i tested the signup form on the app running on the EC2 instance, it wouldn't store the user data into the MySQL database on RDS. However, it would store it in the DB on RDS if I ran the app locally. So this led me to believe it was an issue of EC2 not having correct access to RDS.

The problem is that I was very familiar with EC-classic, but now my region doesn't allow it and I have to use VPC.

Now, I can't even connect to the RDS database... I've tried setting up a different VPC all together, but no luck. I have a feeling it has to do with subnets/security groups. I have allowed all IP's (0.0.0.0/0) access to SSH, HTTP, HTTPS, MYSQL(3600).. inbound. Outbound has all ip's allowed for all ports.

Comment: for one mysql is 3306

Answer (score 1):

Since RDS requires you to have two availability zones when deploying in a VPC, you need to make sure that beanstalk is able to get to both of them via Network ACLs as well as the permissions for the instance based security groups.

Only your ELB and your NAT instance/NAT gateway need to be public subnets, everything else should be in private subnets.

Security groups are stateful and network groups are stateless so while you only need to allow inbound rules for the security groups, you need to allow BOTH inbound and outbound ports from your beanstalk subnet to both RDS subnets using Network ACLs.  See [Security in Your VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Security.html).

Here is a sample `eb create` to create the beanstalk environment (replace square bracketed strings):

`eb create [BEANSTALK_ENVIRONMENT] --instance_type m3.medium --branch_default --cname [BEANSTALK_CNAME] --database --database.engine postgres --database.version [x] --database.size 100 --database.instance db.m4.large --database.password xxxxxxxxx --database.username ebroot --instance_profile [BEANSTALK_EC2_IAM_PROFILE] --keyname [SSH_KEY_NAME] --platform "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.3.0 running Ruby 2.2" --region us-east-1 --tags tag1=value1,tag2=value2 --tier webserver --verbose --sample --vpc.id [vpc-xxxxxx] --vpc.dbsubnets [subnet-db000001,subnet-db000002] --vpc.ec2subnets [subnet-ec200001] --vpc.elbsubnets [subnet-elb00001] --vpc.elbpublic --vpc.securitygroups [sg-00000001] --sample --timeout 3600`

subnet-db000001 NETWORK ACL RULES:

```
Inbound: Port Range: 5432, Source [subnet-ec200001 (as ip range)], Allow
Outbound: Port Range: 5432, Source [subnet-ec200001 (as ip range)], Allow
```

subnet-db000002 NETWORK ACL RULES:

```
Inbound: Port Range: 5432, Source [subnet-ec200001 (as ip range)], Allow
Outbound: Port Range: 5432, Source [subnet-ec200001 (as ip range)], Allow
```

subnet-ec200001 NETWORK ACL RULES:

```
Inbound: Port Range: 5432, Source [subnet-db000001 (as ip range)], Allow
Inbound: Port Range: 5432, Source [subnet-db000002 (as ip range)], Allow
Outbound: Port Range: 5432, Source [subnet-db000001 (as ip range)], Allow
Outbound: Port Range: 5432, Source [subnet-db000002 (as ip range)], Allow
```

subnet-elb00001 NETWORK ACL RULES:

```
Inbound: Port Range: 80, Source 0.0.0.0/0, Allow
Inbound: Port Range: 443, Source 0.0.0.0/0, Allow
Outbound: Port Range: 80, Source 0.0.0.0/0, Allow
Outbound: Port Range: 443, Source 0.0.0.0/0, Allow
```

An additional note about Network ACLs -- many services don't respond on the original port but use an [ephemeral port](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html#VPC_ACLs_Ephemeral_Ports). So you may have to add the following to the inbound AND outbound network ACLs for subnets with EC2 instances:

```
Outbound: Port Range: 1024-65535, Source 0.0.0.0/0, Allow
Outbound: Port Range: 1024-65535, Source 0.0.0.0/0, Allow
```

There are also several useful scenarios in [Recommended Network ACL Rules for Your VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_NACLs.html).

I hope this helps.